# csv extension primitives not recognized

Tags: csv, netlogo

I am somewhat new to using NetLogo extensions and I'm having some trouble. I downloaded the csv extension from https://github.com/NetLogo/CSV-Extension/releases, copied the folder into the extensions folder of NetLogo, and added

```
extensions [ csv ]
```

to the beginning of my script. However, when I try to use the primitive `csv:to-file`, it is not recognized. I've tried other primitives as well but none of them seem to work. Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Did you declare the extension at the top of your code file?  (Also, what platform are you using?)

Comment: Recent versions of NetLogo include the CSV extension — it isn't something you need to separately download anymore. Are you using an old version of NetLogo?

Comment: I did declare the extension at the beginning of my code file so it should be recognized. I am using Netlogo 5.3.1

Comment: I went back and checked the extensions folder on my laptop to see if the csv extension cane with this version of Netlogo and copied that version back to my desktop. Now everything seems to work. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of NetLogo include the CSV extension — it isn't something you need to separately download anymore.

If you're using an old version of NetLogo, upgrade.

If you're using a recent version of NetLogo that includes the CSV extension, remove the extra one you added. (At that point it should work, but if not, uninstall then re-install NetLogo to 100% ensure that the original state is restored.)